# Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now; PHP While loop

Tags: php, mysql

When running the below code, on the second loop (it loops the quantity amount of times) it gives me a Commands out of sync error. What is causing this?

PHP Code:

```
while ($i < $quantity) {
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($con, "
        INSERT INTO parts (capacity, length, width, height, orientation, weight, location, description, status, partNumber) VALUES ('$capacity', '$length', '$width', '$height', '$orient', '$weight', '$location', '$desc', '$status', '$partNum');

        INSERT INTO craneparts (craneID, partsID) VALUES ('$craneID', LAST_INSERT_ID());
    ") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Wasn't aware there was a `mysqli_multi_query`...so much to learn

Comment: I know! I only learnt about it earlier today. Never would have even considered the possibility until I came across the need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in
>   your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and
>   try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result().
>   It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
>   without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

Try calling [mysqli_next_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php) between your mysqli_multi_query calls

```
while ($i < $quantity) {
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($con, "
        INSERT INTO parts (capacity, length, width, height, orientation, weight, location, description, status, partNumber) VALUES ('$capacity', '$length', '$width', '$height', '$orient', '$weight', '$location', '$desc', '$status', '$partNum');

        INSERT INTO craneparts (craneID, partsID) VALUES ('$craneID', LAST_INSERT_ID());
    ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con)) {;} // flush multi_queries

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Got this error
`mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`

Comment: @LiggyRide looks like mysqli_free_result isn't the right way to go since mysqli_multi_query doesn't return a result object. can you try again with mysqli_next_result()?

Comment: `mysqli_next_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given` boolean given was same as in the mysqli_free_result() also, just cut that part out.

Comment: Trying the code you edited your post with, sorry for not reading that first.

Comment: Gives me this response: `Strict Standards: mysqli_next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method` but it works. Is this okay or is more troubleshooting needed?

Comment: @LiggyRide It's just a notice so it's ok but I updated the code to prevent the notice